# Flutter tree view widget and firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, treeview

How do we get the firestore data into the treeview widget? I tried everything to format the data into array but didn't go well. I just started learning flutter and firestore and is my first project.

[Flutter TreeView Json Data Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57784727/flutter-treeview-json-data-parsing)

Answer (score 0):

Check [flutter_simple_treeview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_simple_treeview). You can feed any widget to be a node. So, you need to convert each record to [TreeNode](https://github.com/google/flutter.widgets/blob/master/packages/flutter_simple_treeview/lib/src/tree_node.dart) object and feed it to the widget TreeView. 
This is [a demo](https://flutter_simple_treeview.codemagic.app).